# Why would isset() return null?

Tags: php, isset

I was getting an error and found `isset()` was not working as expected.

I discovered it was returning null instead of false; how this can happen?

My test code:

```
echo 'COUNT : '.count($_GET).', ISSET : '.(isset($_GET['test'])==null);
```

returns : COUNT : 0, ISSET : 1

Comment: It is not returning null! Add another `=` -> `===` and you get false! [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: You've done a loose comparison with == and PHP will coerce `null` to `false`. Do a strict comparison with `===` and you'll get a different result.

Comment: @Rizier123 please answer the question (rather than comment) so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044932/why-would-isset-return-null?noredirect=1#comment46329496_29044932) requested.

`isset()` is not returning `NULL`! It's because of the [comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) which treats `NULL` as `FALSE`. You can see this in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

Also if you take a look into the manual of `isset()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

You will see that it only returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`:

> **Returns TRUE** if var exists and has value other than NULL, **FALSE otherwise.**

Now to fix this you can simply change `==` to this `===`, so that the comparison also compares the type.

Comment: also you can use strict comparative operators such as === or !==